# Обработк ошибок на jquery-ajax + JAX-RS

Tags: java, jquery

Кто может поделитесь простым примером, как вы отправляете информативное сообщение, в случае обработки запроса ajax, когда нужно вернуть ошибку.

Как это выглядит на стороне сервера и как это выглядит на стороне клиента

вот например, мой пример

```
/* формирование ajax-запроса, на проверку аутентификации*/

 function isAuthentication(email, password) {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/employees/auth/signin/' + email + '/' + password,
    method: 'get',
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {

        successAuth();

     },
    error: function (data) {

        handlingErrStatusQueryAuth(data);
    }
    });
  }


 var notAccess = "Доступ запрещен!";
 var notAccessEn = "Access denied!"

var successAuth = function () {
$(".authentication").html("OK").css("color","red");

  }

 /*обработка запроса на аутентификацию*/
 var handlingErrStatusQueryAuth = function (data) {

    if (data.status === 401) {

    $(".authentication").html("");
   // $(".authentication").css('color', red);
    $(".authentication").html(notAccess).css("color", "red");

     }
   }
```

а это сторона сервера

```
  /**
 * Проверка аутентификации пользователя
 * @param email
   * @param password
 */
    @GET
 @Path( "/auth/signin/{email}/{password}" )
  public Response isValidUser(@PathParam( "email" ) String email,
                            @PathParam( "password" ) String password) {

    EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDaoImpl();

    Employee employee = dao.loadEmployeeByFieldStr("email", email);

    String passwordTarget = employee.getPassword();

    if (employee != null && password.equals(passwordTarget)) {
        Response.ResponseBuilder status = Response.ok();
        Response response = status.build();

        return response;
    } else {
        Response.ResponseBuilder status = Response.status(401);
        Response response = status.build();

        return response;
    }
    }
```

Как это можно переделать, в соответствии с моим вопросом?

Чуть ниже указал ссылку на сайт, где показан один из вариантов, использования
**WebApplicationException**

Comment: [ссылка](https://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-parameter-classes/)

Answer (score 1):

Я использую php так что бэкенд не буду описывать просто покажу как я принимаю и обрабатываю ответы, а о серверной части расскажу абстрактно.

Для фронтэнда использую JS плагин [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/). Благо алерты на нем делаются моментально и очень красиво. Устанавливается быстро, не имеет зависимостей от `jquery` или `bootstrap`.

На сервере я генерирую строку в json формате и статус 200 - выполнено, или ошибку 404, 403, 401 и т.д.

JSON

```
{
    "message": "Данные успешно удалены",
    "action": "redirect|reload|close",
    "uri": "http://mydomain.com"
}
```

`action` это действие которое будет после того как пользователь закроет уведомление

`redirect + uri` - переадресация, `reload` - перезагрузка страницы, `close` - закрытие уведомления и больше ничего (только когда статус 200).

А вот собственно и сам код

```
function errorHandler(response) {
    try {
        var answer = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        var message = answer.message !== undefined ? answer.message : 'Неизвестная ошибка!';
        swal({
            type: 'error',
            text: message,
            title: 'Ошибка!',
            html: true
        });
    } catch (err) {
        swal({
            type: 'error',
            text: response.responseText,
            title: 'Ошибка',
            html: true
        });
    }
}

function successHandler(response) {
    try {
        var func;

        var answer = JSON.parse(response);
        var message = answer.hasOwnProperty('message') ? answer.message : 'Все гуд!';

        var action = answer.hasOwnProperty('action') ? answer.action : 'reload';

        if (action == 'redirect') {
            func = function () {
                window.location.href = answer.uri;
            }
        } else if (action == 'reload') {
            func = function () {
                location.reload();
            };
        } else if (action == 'close') {
            func = function () {
                swal.close();
            };
        }

        swal({
            type: 'success',
            text: message,
            title: 'Выполнено',
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, func);

    } catch (err) {
        elog(response);
        swal({
            type: 'error',
            text: response,
            title: 'Ошибка',
            html: true
        });
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/',
    data: {},
    success: function (answer) {
        successHandler(answer);
    },
    error: function (answer) {
        errorHandler(answer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для различных видов ошибокможно использовать разные исключения и механизм их перехватчиков, оборачивающих исключения в ответ сервера с определённым типом ошибок (HTTP статусом).
Соответственно, на беке останется просто время от времени выбрасывать исключения с желаемым текстом, дополнительно описывающим ситуацию. Не забываем логирование на уровне ERROR.
На фронте можно просто воспользоваться статусной панкелькой для вывода сообщений с разноцветной подсветкой (красный - критические ошибки, жёлтый - предупреждения, зелёный - информационные соообщения) - такие элементы интерфейса доступны в инструментах на подобие Bootstrap.